# Managing systemd services on read-only filesystem

Tags: systemd, embedded, readonly

I am looking for strategies how to manage enabling and disabling of systemd services on a read-only filesystem. It's not possible as the multi-user.target.wants directory contents get modified.

Keeping /etc/systemd/system as the default location for services, has anyone tried ways to manage the launch 'table' / multi-user.target.wants directory such that an application or script running on the target can still enable or disable a specific service (or services) even though the filesystem is RO?

I have thought to symlink the multi-user.target.wants directory to a location on a small rw "config" partition and switch between pre-set multi-user.target.wants directories on boot/reboot according to the need. Alternatively, I suppose a script or application could directly modify this symlinked location by adding or removing entries from it.

I have not tested that yet; I wanted to see if anyone has experience with this, possible strategies, or know of a more standardized approach to this? Thank you.

Comment: Since filesystem is readonly, you will not be able to make user.target.wants a symbol link. Enabling or Disabling services means permanently change config, which requires a writable filesystem. Try to use an overlayfs as your root filesystem

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I need to enable dm-verity on the rootfs and this is the reason to pursue read only. Do you know, is it possible to use dm verity with overlay fs (can it be targeted to only apply to the lower fs)?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but too much detail for a comment.

To make a change, you need write access to that filesystem.  I'm guessing you have write-access now, but you want to lock-it-down read-only while still being able to make these changes later.

`systemd` will search for unit paths in several places in `/run` which will not be read-only.  There may be an opportunity for you to load a service very early and create/edit some units in one of these load paths:

Reference: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path

| Path | Description |
| --- | --- |
| /etc/systemd/system.control | Persistent and transient configuration created using the dbus API |
| /run/systemd/system.control | " |
| /run/systemd/transient | Dynamic configuration for transient units |
| /run/systemd/generator.early | Generated units with high priority (see early-dir in systemd.generator(7)) |
| /etc/systemd/system | System units created by the administrator |
| /run/systemd/system | Runtime units |
| /run/systemd/generator | Generated units with medium priority (see normal-dir in systemd.generator(7)) |
| /usr/local/lib/systemd/system | System units installed by the administrator |
| /usr/lib/systemd/system | System units installed by the distribution package manager |
| /run/systemd/generator.late | Generated units with low priority (see late-dir in systemd.generator(7)) |

It may be possible for you to write an application which runs very early during boot which connects to a socket to your command-center, gets instructions for units, then uses the dbus-API to create units in `/run/systemd/system.control`

Another option is writing a generator.  See [systemd.generator(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html#) for details.  Generators are programs that are executed by systemd early in the boot-process (before unit files are loaded).  These generators are expected to generate unit files, drop-ins, or symbolic links in places like `/run/systemd/generator/`.  That would be outside of your read-only filesystem.

An example of a generator is `systemd-fstab-generator` which reads `/etc/fstab` and generates native systemd `*.mount` units.

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed response. I will review this in detail next week when I have more time. I suspect I can find my solution somewhere here!